# Alterar idioma do osticket

Tags: instalador

Instalei o osticket numa máquina virtual com o ubuntu server 16.04, onde está tudo a funcionar corretamente.
o idioma está em inglês como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora pretendo alterar o idioma do osticket de Inglês para Português, alguém sabe como o fazer?

Comment: Baixe o [pack](http://osticket.com/download/go?dl=lang%2Fsk.phar) e extraia ou faça o upload no diretório `include/i18n`

Comment: @NoobSaibot, pode dizer as linhas de comando para fazer o upload no diretório?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisara baixar pacote de idioma. Acesse a página
http://osticket.com/download, de pois selecione a aba Language Packages, e abaixo vai ter uma listagem com vários pacotes de tradução.

Então basta baixar o pacote de idioma e fazer o upload do arquivo `phar` para a pasta `include/i18n` da sua instalação do osTicket.

---

Para baixar pode utilizar o WGET, assim:

```
wget http://osticket.com/sites/default/files/download/lang/pt_BR.phar
```

ou transferir o arquivo para a pasta no Linux, para isso pode usar o WinSCP, do qual da para visualizar as pastas no linux e transferir pelo windows.

Comment: Já fiz o download, pode dizer as linhas de comando para fazer o upload para a pasta include/i18n?

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo

Comment: já fiz o download, como faço o upload para a pasta include/i18n?

Comment: tentou com uma das 2 formas que citei na resposta ?

Comment: fiz esta forma `wget http://osticket.com/sites/default/files/download/lang/pt_BR.phar`, mas basta esta linha de comando? Esta linha de comando não faz só o download?

Comment: fiz o download como mostrei acima, agora falta me a linha de comando para fazer o upload do arquivo `phar` para a pasta `include/i18n`

Comment: dentro da pasta do OsTicket vai ter a pasta include/i18n, coloque o arquivo la dentro .. algo como /var/www/htdocs/osticket/

Comment: ou /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/ticket.domain.com/include/